# How can i accept Bitcoin donations or payments on my website?

Tags: payment

I have seen all these other posts on how to do it, but they are all so complicated, what is the quickest, easiesy way to accept Bitcoin payments or donations on my website? Why is it all so difficult?

Answer (score 3):

BitPay is an electronic payment processing system for the bitcoin currency. It enables online merchants to accept bitcoins, as a form of payment, just as they accept payments from Visa, Mastercard, or Paypal.

BitPay is available in every country, and you can set your prices in over 30 different currencies.

Merchants choosing to keep the bitcoins can be anywhere in the world. Merchants in some countries can choose to receive a direct deposit into their bank account.

Answer (score 2):

Well - the easiest way would be to just put your wallet address up on your site so people could send you Bitcoin directly.  You could also use sites like Blockchain.info or follow this tutorial (http://bitcoinmoney.com/post/9678390130/wolfram-alpha-qr-code-generator) to create a QR code from your wallet address as well.

Alternatively, Coinbase (https://coinbase.com/merchants), BitPay (https://bitpay.com), and Mt. Gox (https://www.mtgox.com/merchant/checkout) all offer tools for merchants to offer Bitcoin payments.  Also - Shopify.com recently announced that they would allow merchants to collect payments via Bitcoin.